# Redirect to setup if config is missing

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to create a basic java web app using servlet 3.0. 
Now, my application needs to run through a basic setup page/form so it knows where to store config files etc. What would be a good way to implement this?

I was thinking of a filter, but since i cant do a redirect, that seems like the wrong way.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean a wizard? Have you seen how a WAR is deployed in Websphere? You have to go through many pages.

Comment: Well, it's not really a wizard. Just a simple form with a couple of field inputs.

Comment: You can do a redirect from inside a filter. No problem with that. `response.sendRedirect(...)`, just like in a servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that a `Filter` would be a great approach to what you're trying to accomplish:

```
@WebFilter
public class ConfigFilter implements Filter {
    @Inject
    private SessionBean session;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String requestURI = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
        if(!session.hasConfig() && !requestURI.startsWith("/configWizard.xhtml")) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("/configWizard.xhtml");
        }
        else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, but i will also need to check that the request does not contain "configWizard" or else it will go in a loop?

Comment: If the filter is also mapped to the URL of the config wizard, then yes, you should do this check.